# Using numba to speed up a Metropolis algorithm

Tags: python, loops, numba, montecarlo, boundary

I am testing how much numba can help in speeding up a classical Metropolis algorithm, e.g. hard-disks in a box:

```
def Metropolis2D(L, d_ex, n_steps, delta):
    
    for steps in range(n_steps):
        a = rm.choice(L)
        b = [a[0] + rm.uniform(-delta, delta), a[1] + rm.uniform(-delta, delta)]
        min_dist = min((b[0] - c[0]) ** 2 + (b[1] - c[1]) ** 2 for c in L if c != a)
        box_cond = min(b[0], b[1]) <= d_ex or max(b[0], b[1]) >= 1.0 - d_ex
        if not (box_cond or min_dist < 4.0 * d_ex ** 2):
            a[:] = b
    return L

Metropolis2D_jit = njit()(Metropolis2D)
```

For example, let us consider the following settings:

```
ell = 4
N = ell**2 # number of disks
eta = 0.65 # disk density 
d_ex = math.sqrt(eta / (math.pi * N)) # radius of the N disks at density eta
del_xy = 1 / (2 * ell) # helf lattice spacing for the initial configuration
L = [[del_xy + i * 2 * del_xy, del_xy + j * 2 * del_xy] for i in range(ell) for j in range(ell)]
n_steps = 1
delta = 2 * (del_xy - d_ex)  # maximal displacement along x or y
```

We are starting from all disks aligned on a square grid at a relatively high (0.65) density of them on the unit square. A single MC move (i.e. n_steps = 1) in the non-jitted Metropolis function requires then:

```
%timeit Metropolis2D_jit(L, d_ex, n_steps, delta)
7.01 µs ± 11.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

However, when running Metropolis2D_jit, I get the following error:

```
UnsupportedError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: inline calls to locally defined closures)
The use of yield in a closure is unsupported.

File "../../../var/folders/q9/jzmgl38d1h5gnmkllt_ly8rr0000gn/T/ipykernel_28212/2383793983.py", line 6:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

*Do you have ideas on how to circumvent this problem and exploit numba speed-up?*

Indeed, one possibility would be to write a partially jitted function, where the disk-disk distance is jitted in numba. However, I was curious if there are solutions to have a full jit of the function Metropolis2D.

Comment: The error is pretty clear "*The use of yield in a closure is * **unsupported**". I do not see how did you deduce that is comes from bound-checking (especially since enabling it does solve the unrelated issue)... Just *uses a basic loop* to compute the mean.

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71956917/5140209

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for your reply. 1) I have tried enabling bounds-checking via [Metropolis2D_jit = njit(boundscheck=True)(Metropolis2D)] but the error persists. 2) I am not sure to entirely understand your comment: which mean? In the Metropolis2D function there are no averages involved.

Comment: Thank you @Ir1985 ! I missed this post. I am checking it now.

Comment: @Ivan 1) I did not mean you you enable bound-checking I actually say the opposite: your problem has no relation with that so it is completely normal it does not fix it. 2) Sorry I meant `min` and not `mean` (for `min_dist`).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jérôme Richard. You are right: it has nothing to do with bound-checking (I am amending the question). I fixed *min* by means of a loop and corrected some issues due to the adoption of rm.choice(). This is an attempted solution that compiles now in numba without errors:

```
import numba as nb
import random as rm

@nb.njit()
def dist_sq_jit(b, c): 
    return (b[0] - c[0]) ** 2 + (b[1] - c[1]) ** 2

@nb.njit()
def Metropolis2D_jit(L, d_ex, n_steps, delta):
    
    for steps in range(n_steps):
        
        ran_ind = np.random.randint(0, len(L))
        a = L[ran_ind]
        b = [a[0] + rm.uniform(-delta, delta), a[1] + rm.uniform(-delta, delta)]
        
        L_sliced = np.concatenate((L[:ran_ind], L[ran_ind + 1:]), axis = 0)
        min_dist = np.zeros(len(L))
        i = -1
        for c in L_sliced: 
            i += 1
            min_dist[i] = dist_sq_jit(b, c)
        
        if (min(b) >= d_ex and max(b) <= 1.0 - d_ex and min(min_dist) >= 4.0 * d_ex ** 2):
            L[ran_ind] = b
            
    return L
```

The computation time (same parameters' settings as above, only change: L is now a numpy array) is reduced by roughly a factor 5:

```
L_vec = np.array(L)
%timeit Metropolis2D_jit(L_vec, d_ex, n_steps, delta)
1.39 µs ± 30.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Perhaps there is room for further improvements?